# Can CxxTest Do Paramaterized Tests?

Tags: tdd, googletest, cxxtest

According to [this](http://meekrosoft.wordpress.com/2009/10/04/testing-c-code-with-the-googletest-framework/) article, one can make a parameterized test in the GoogleTest framework with some code like this:

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(InstantiationName,
                        MyStringTest,
                        ::testing::Values("meek", "geek", "freek"));

TEST_P(MyStringTest, acceptsEekyWords)
{
  ASSERT_TRUE(acceptName(GetParam()));
}
```

plus some scaffolding.

After going through the [CxxTest User Guide](http://cxxtest.com/guide.html), I couldn't help but notice the lack of any mention of parameterized tests. Are parameterized tests even possible with CxxTest?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762968/can-cxxtest-suite-be-dynamically-extended-at-run-time) seems to address something similar, but the answer is by no means trivial.

I'm new to C++ unit testing. Maybe parameterized tests aren't a big deal? Almost all of my tests were parameterized in my last C# NUnit project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my answer to the other question you cited, there's no facility for generating tests at run time, which is what any parameter-based tester I've ever seen does. In CxxTest, the test list is determined at compile time by the Python-based C++ parser, `cxxtestgen`. You can [generate suites dynamically](http://cxxtest.com/guide.html#_customizing_test_fixtures), but you only have the option of generating zero or one copy of any suite.